# Obtain the type of archive

Tags: php, file, mime, substr, strpos

I'm trying to obtain the type of archive in php with `strops` and `substr`.

How can I find the position of the first point from the end of the name of the file?

```
$archive_name=$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];

$type=substr($archive_name, strpos(".") )  ?
```

Comment: tje answer to your question is strrpos (string reverse position :D) http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php Answers below are probably answers to the actual underlying problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [pathinfo](http://docs.php.net/pathinfo) for that.
But instead of relying on the filename I'd rather suggest using [fileinfo](http://docs.php.net/fileinfo)

> The functions in this module try to guess the content type and encoding of a file by looking for certain magic byte sequences at specific positions within the file. While this is not a bullet proof approach the heuristics used do a very good job.